# Can I make a TTreeNode invisible?

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-2007

TTreeNode does not have a Visible property, so the obvious option does not exist. Is there any other way to make a TTreeNode and all its child nodes invisible? Of course I want to be able to make it visible again later.

This is with Delphi 2007.

Note#1: I am aware of the alternative TVirtualTreeView, and I will check it out if there is no easy way to accomplish this with TTreeView.

Note#2: I need the option only for top level nodes. The ones I want to hide usually don't even have children.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a good idea to **separate data from the user interface**, and this issue with tree views is a good example - **don't store data in a tree view**.  I often have a non-visual unit that contains a structured class that stores data.  A user interface unit can have a treeview that can displays (a configurable subset of) data from that class.  There are a variety of ways to move data between the two.  This type of isolation requires a bit of planning, but provides much greater flexibility and stability.

Comment: While that is not the answer I wanted to hear, I guess it is the only possible solution so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to use a better tree component, why not use Virtualtreeview. It is one of the best components ever developed for Delphi and it's free to use with source! But there is maybe a logical problem with hiding a ttreenode! Should the tree show a + sign when no nodes are visible?

http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/VirtualTreeview

Answer (score 4):

TTreeView is a wrapper for the standard Windows tree view, which (judging from the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760017(VS.85).aspx)) doesn't allow to hide tree nodes. It does make sense too, as the tree view is known to not scale to a large number of nodes, so hiding tree nodes instead of removing everything that isn't necessary would be a bad idea.

You can make your life a little easier if you remove and insert only the top level node (the one you wish to hide), and create all child nodes in the *OnExpanding* event of the re-added node. For that you just need to set the *HasChildren* property of the node to true.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to "hide" a node in TTreeView is to actually remove it.  Then, to "show" the node, you simply re-insert it again.

Answer (score 4):

How I made it in DXE5 with standard TTreeView. I think it will be helpful for some guys. I've made it simple for example:

**1. Item that must be hidden. I set ImageIndex of it to 2.**

```
  var
    Node:TTreeNode;
  begin
  ...
  Node:=Tree.Items.AddChild(ParentNode,'Text');
  Node.ImageIndex:=2;
```

**2. Now I set onAdvancedCustomDrawItem event of TTreeView.**

```
  if Node.ImageIndex=2 then
  begin
    DefaultDraw:=false;
    Node.Parent.HasChildren:=false;
  end;
```

**3. Check it with onClick event of TTreeView:**

```
var
 Tree:TTreeView;
 Node:TTreeNode;
begin
  Tree:=Sender as TTreeView;
  if Tree.Selected.Index>-1 then
   if Tree.Selected.HasChildren then
    if Tree.Selected.getFirstChild.ImageIndex=2 then
     showmessage(Tree.Selected.getFirstChild.Text);
```

Done. I hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this issue by moving the node to another non-expanded node and vice versa.
I done it in the on expanding event handler.